# Spiral diamond -print pattern

Tags: java

I'm currently try to print below pattern in java,please help me in solving it.

Input: `3, abcdefghijklm`

output:

```
  c
 bjd
aimke
 hlf
  g
```

I build diamond pattern with star, stuck in print values from array in spirally in diamond shape show above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void rhombus() {
    int n = 3;
    int size = 2 * n - 1;
    char[][] sol = new char[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            sol[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    int i = size / 2;
    int j = 0;
    String s = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    int len = s.length();
    int in = 0;
    int left = 0, top = 0, right = size - 1;
    int bottom = size - 1;
    boolean flag = false;
    while (i != j) {
        while (i >= top && !flag) {
            sol[i][j] = s.charAt((in++) % len);
            if (i == size / 2 && j == size / 2)
                flag = true;
            i--;
            j++;
        }
        if (flag == true)
            break;
        i += 2;
        top++;
        left++;
        while (j <= right && !flag) {
            sol[i][j] = s.charAt((in++) % len);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        j -= 2;
        right--;
        while (i <= bottom && !flag) {
            sol[i][j] = s.charAt((in++) % len);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        bottom--;
        i -= 2;
        while (j >= left && !flag) {
            sol[i][j] = s.charAt((in++) % len);
            i--;
            j--;
        }
        j++;
    }
    sol[i][j] = s.charAt((in++) % len);
    for (int a = 0; a < size; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < size; b++) {
            System.out.print(sol[a][b]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class DiamondStarPattern {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i =1; i<4;i++) {
      for(int j=3;j>=i;j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int k=1;k<=i;k++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++) {
      for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for(int k =1;k<4-i;k++) {
        System.out.print(" *");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Diamond_pattern {
     public static void main( String args[]){
         
     
    int n=10; //change this as you want
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        
            for(int j=1; j<=n-i; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
            
            
            for(int j=1;j<=(2*i-1);j++)
            System.out.print("*");
            
            System.out.println("");
            
        }
            for( int i=(n-1); i>=1;i--){
            for(int j=1;j<=n-i;j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for( int j=(2*i-1);j>=1;j--)
                    System.out.print("*");
           
            System.out.println("");
          
            } 
        
    
}
}
```